# Is there a purpose for UPDATE ... WHERE but with same values?

Tags: mariadb, query, update, php

I am translating some code from PHP to Python, and I came upon this interesting snippet:

```php
$sql11 = "UPDATE tbl_pas SET api_id_pas='" . $api['kd_pas'] . 
         "' WHERE api_id_pas='" . $api['kd_pas'] .
         "' AND api_id_sam='" . $api['id_sam'] . "'";
$query11 = $this->db->query($sql11);
```

(And yeah, I know that's Bad Code™ for not using parametrization, but it's being replaced anyways, so that's not the point)

The database is MariaDB, accessed using PDO.

Now let's say `$api['kd_pas'] == "abc"` and `$api['id_sam'] == "def"`, the query then becomes:

```sql
UPDATE tbl_pas SET api_id_pas = 'abc' WHERE api_id_pas = 'abc' AND api_id_sam = 'def'
```

I am wondering, what is the purpose of such update statement? After all, it's replacing `api_id_pas` with the *exact same* value.

I personally think this query is useless and can be taken out (i.e., not translated at all), but I'd like to know your opinion.

Comment: If there are triggers or timestamp columns the `UPDATE` may have a noticeable effect.

Comment: @stickybit ahhh, makes sense! Thanks, I'll check for triggers/timestamps. If there aren't any, then I guess it's okay to just remove that code.